# C++ script sometimes runs and sometimes hangs

Tags: c++, vector, tree, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to do some genetic programming in C++. I've put together a version of this code in Python and it worked fine (it was just FAR TOO SLOW). The basic premise is viewing programs as tree-like expressions and evolving those.

Here is the code to create just one candidate tree (trees are stored as vectors of nodes which point to their children by the index of the child node in the same vector) (see grow_tree function):

This code compiles fine :) I'm compiling using g++ to get an a.out file which I run using ./a.out

My problem is that sometimes it runs and completes fine and sometimes it just hangs and doesn't do anything (doesn't give me an error either)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>

const int MAX_TREE_DEPTH = 5;

int randint(int min, int max) {
    return (rand() % ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
}

struct node {
    int type, op, req_ch;
    std::vector<int> ch;
    std::map<std::string, float> params;
    node(int p, int rem_depth) {
        if ((p == -1) || (p == 0)) {
            req_ch = 2;
            if (rem_depth >= 2) { 
                type = randint(0, 1); 
                if (type == 0) { 
                    op = randint(0, 1); 
                } else if (type == 1) { 
                    op = randint(2, 5); 
                }
            } else { 
                type = 1; 
                op = randint(2, 5); 
            }
        } else if (p == 1) { 
            type = 2;  
            if (rem_depth >= 1) { 
                op =  randint(6, 11); 
            } else { op = 11; }
            if ((op >= 6) && (op <= 10)) { 
                req_ch = 2; 
            } else if (op >= 11) { req_ch = 0; }
        }
    }    
};

void grow_tree(std::vector<node>* func, int p, int rem_depth) {
    node n(p, rem_depth);
    func->push_back(n);
    int i = func->size() - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < n.req_ch; j++) {
        func->at(i).ch.push_back(func->size());
        grow_tree(func, n.type, rem_depth - 1);
    }
}


struct rule {
    float score;
    bool scored;
    std::vector<node> func;
    rule(int m) {
        if (m == 0) { // Random initialisation
            int depth = randint(2, MAX_TREE_DEPTH);
            grow_tree(&func, -1, depth);
        }
    }
};


int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));  // Seed the random number generator
    int depth = randint(2, MAX_TREE_DEPTH);
    std::vector<node> f;
    grow_tree(&f, -1, depth);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *My problem is that sometimes it runs and completes fine and sometimes it just hangs and doesn't do anything* -- Which more than likely means your program has one or more bugs.  Advice -- debug your program with *known* data that produces the problem, not randomized data.  By using randomized data, you cannot center on the issue easily.  Log the values you use when you use random data that causes the issue, then rewrite your program to hardcode those values so that you get a consistent failing case.

Comment: There are cases where you don’t assign values to all members of a `node`.

Comment: And to add to @molbdnilo comment, you could check this by printing out the values of `op` `p`, etc. before you return from the `node` constructor, to confirm exactly what values are being used.  If one of those values is "wild", then this is one way to confirm you're using an uninitialized value.  Or you can initialize everything to `-1` and see if any of those values remain `-1`, again confirming you did not set all the values in the constructor.  It's all about debugging and learning how to  debug code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the performance of the Python code versus the C++ code?  In my experience, typically, Python takes twice as long to run.  But there can be mitigating factors that may make it have parity with C++, or C++ may be significantly faster (an order of magnitude, perhaps even two orders of magnitude).  And that's with "everything else being equal" (e.g., same algorithm; appropriate data structures).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @molbdnilo, your `node` constructor is susceptible to having variables that are uninitialized after the constructor returns.  You then use the `node` instance variable(s) here in `grow_tree`:

`for (int j = 0; j < n.req_ch; j++) {`

If `n.req_ch` is an uninitialized or "wild" value, the loop could go on for a very long time.  Imagine if `n.req_ch` came back with a value of something close to (assuming 32-bit integers), `2^32 - 1`.  Your loop will be going on for over 2,000,000,000 iterations.

To confirm this, if you initialized your member of variables of `node` to a value, you can easily output those variables to see if the initial value was changed.  If the value wasn't changed, this confirms you are using uninitialized values in your `grow_tree` function.

Example:

```
node(int p, int rem_depth) :type(-100), op(-100), req_ch(-100) // Initialize everything to -100
{
   // your code
 ...
   // now check if all the variables have been initialized (values were changed from -100)
   if ( type == -100 || op == -100 || req_ch == -100 )
   {
       std::cout << "Oops.  I'm using uninitialized values for p = " << p << 
      " rem_depth = " << rem_depth << "\n";
       std::cout << type << " " << op << " " << req_ch << "\n\n";
    }   
}
```

[Here is your code, modified with the check.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78ca430af8f5b11d)

As you can see, your `node` constructor does not set all the values, and you wind up using those values later on in `grow_tree`.

So the answer to your issue is to go back and plug up the hole in the `node` constructor so that your variables are initialized.